# What are the correct group and artifact ids for Java EE 5 and 6 artifacts?

Tags: java, maven-2, jakarta-ee, maven

So far we have been manually downloading the jars and deploying to our maven repo with custom group/artifact ids. I would like to avoid that. So my question is

1. What are the correct group and
   artifact id's for Java EE 5 and 6
   artifacts? I'd like to get the names at JSR level (for example I doesn't need the ids for Java EE 6 uber jar but individual apis like jsr 330 etc)
2. Which is the CORRECT repo to get these from? Does Oracle host there in their own repos?

My main interest is in the [APIs listed here for Java EE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html) and [here for Java EE 5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/javaee5-jsp-135162.html), each one as a separate artifact

---

[Here is the Oracle mvn repository information](http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.0.1-final.html) from where you can download Java EE 6 artifacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the official repository and artifact id's for Java EE 5 and 6

Java EE 5 : http://download.java.net/maven/2/javaee/javaee-api/5/

Java EE 6 : http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/javaee-api/6.0/

Answer (score 6):

Most JSR and Java EE artifacts have artifactIds starting with `javax`

E.g. the dependency for JSR-330 is this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

Most standard APIs are available in the central repo and hence can be found by [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/).

Or you can just browse the `javax` directory of your maven mirror of choice. Here's [javax on ibiblio.org](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/javax)

Sun / Oracle Java API's that are not in central are usually in the download.java.net [maven repo](http://download.java.net/maven/2/)

Comment: I am aware of the above one but seems like that was not from Oracle/Sun (and that is the problem because I can't validate if this is from official source for e.g I saw multiple jars with same group id but different artifact id http://www.mvnbrowser.com/artifacts-browse.html?groupId=javax.inject). Also the version should be "1.0" but in the central repo it says "1"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to get them manually because you need to accept the Sun/Oracle license agreement before using them.