# Adding CDI annotations to utility library while still letting users choose CDI implementation

Tags: java, maven, annotations, cdi

I am maintaining a small open source library written in plain Java SE (https://github.com/tbsalling/aismessages).

I have decided to add Java EE CDI annotations to it (JSR-330, javax.inject). But how can I do this without binding the users of the library to use a specific CDI implementation?

If I add this to `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

are all the users of the library still free to choose their implementation (Weld, Guice, ...) - or will they all need to pull whatever is in the Maven Central repo ?

Would I perhaps need to consider adding

```
    ...
    <scope>provided</scope> 
    ...
```

to the dependency section to achieve this?

Comment: The inject api is supported by all major dependency injection frameworks (even the "standard-compilant" Spring fraemwork). So you will be fine with javax.inject. As for the scope I guess that provided should be okay because the inject library has to be provided by the framework already.

Comment: The CDI tag you used specifically means the JSR 299. It makes this a little confusing imo. Maybe tag additional frameworks that perform DI to clarify that you want to be compliant "over the board".

Comment: Thank you for the input! - I got the JSR-330 impression from another SO answer. Will have to look deeper into that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606757/what-are-the-correct-group-and-artifact-ids-for-java-ee-5-and-6-artifacts